# Cannot get a constant when using statsmodels add_constant

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have the following python code using statsmodels:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Assuming future_time_points is an array like this
future_time_points = np.array([2010])

# Stacking future_time_points and its square
stacked_array = np.column_stack((future_time_points, future_time_points ** 2))

# Adding a constant column to the stacked array
array_with_constant = sm.add_constant(stacked_array)

print(array_with_constant)
```

The output is `[[   2010 4040100]]`

I was expecting the output to have a `1` because I am using `add_constant`, however it is not there, how can I fix it? I am using statsmodels version 0.14.0

Answer (score 0):

The [default behavior of `add_constant()`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tools.tools.add_constant.html#statsmodels-tools-tools-add-constant) is to skip adding anything if a constant is already present.
If  you set the `has_constant` parameter to `raise`, you will get the Exception

```
ValueError: Column(s) 0,1 are constant.
```

Setting the has_constant parameter to `'add'` will add the new constant column you want.  However, I observed that by default it prepended the new column, while the documentation states the default behavior should be to append.  This appears to be a case of the documentation being out of date as the version of the library I just installed has a default value of True for the prepend parameter.

```
# Adding a constant column to the stacked array
array_with_constant = sm.add_constant(stacked_array, has_constant="add")

# Output ->  [[1.0000e+00 2.0100e+03 4.0401e+06]]

---------------------

# Adding a constant column to the stacked array
# With explicit prepend = False
array_with_constant = sm.add_constant(stacked_array, False, has_constant="add")

# Output -> [[2.0100e+03 4.0401e+06 1.0000e+00]]
```

Comment: I dug into the repository a bit, and prepend=True has always been the default behavior, but the documentation was changed several years ago and the changes made the default behavior less clear.  I submitted a bug report for the documentation.